# Make questions appear in random order

Tags: java, android

as you can see in the title I'd like to make my questions appear in random order, but I don't really know how. I have 4 button listeners which update the question after you answered a question and my updatequestion looks like this:

```
private void updateQuestion(){
    mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestionFrankrijk(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1Frankrijk(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2Frankrijk(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3Frankrijk(mQuestionNumber));
    mButtonChoice4.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice4Frankrijk(mQuestionNumber));

    mAnswerFrankrijk = 
mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswerFrankrijk(mQuestionNumber);
    mQuestionNumber++;
}
```

I also have a questionlibrary and I guess I have to give the questions different id's so I can make them appear in different order, but I don't know how and where to apply that in my code.

Questionlibrary:

```
public class QuestionLibrary {

    public static String mQuestionsFrankrijk [] = {
            "Wat is de hoofdstad van Frankrijk?",
            "Wat is de bijnaam van het Franse nationale voetbalelftal",
            "Welke van de volgende landen grenst niet aan Frankrijk?",
            "Bij welke sport hoort 'le maillot jaune'?",
            "Welk museum in Parijs heeft een piramide als ingang?",
            "Hoeveel inwoners heeft Frankrijk?",
            "Het Franse volkslied is een?",
            "Het vliegveld bij Parijs heet",
            "De Romeinse naam voor Parijs is?",
            "Hoeveel departemeneten zijn er in Frankrijk?"
    };

    public static String mChoicesFrankrijk [][] = {
            {"Lyon", "Parijs", "Nice", "Bordeaux"},
            {"La France", "Le Coq Sportif", "Les Bleus", "Les Gagnants"},
            {"Zwitserland", "België", "Spanje", "Oostenrijk"},
            {"Tennis", "Wielrennen", "Rugby", "Cricket"},
            {"Musée d'Orsay", "Musée Rodin", "Louvre", "Centre Georges Pompidou"},
            {"50 miljoen", "60 miljoen", "70 miljoen", "80 miljoen"},
            {"Ballade", "Chanson", "Hymne", "Ode"},
            {"Horla", "Lorly", "Orah", "Orly"},
            {"Arelate", "Augustodonum", "Lugdunum", "Lutetia"},
            {"66", "76", "86", "96"}

    };

    public String mCorrectAnswersFrankrijk [] =
    {"Parijs", "Les Bleus", "Oostenrijk", "Wielrennen", "Louvre", "60 miljoen", "Hymne",
     "Orly", "Lutetia", "96"};



    public String getQuestionFrankrijk(int a) {
        return mQuestionsFrankrijk[a];
    }
    public String getChoice1Frankrijk(int a) {
        return mChoicesFrankrijk[a][0];
    }
    public String getChoice2Frankrijk(int a) {
        return mChoicesFrankrijk[a][1];
    }
    public String getChoice3Frankrijk(int a) {
        return mChoicesFrankrijk[a][2];
    }
    public String getChoice4Frankrijk(int a) {
        return mChoicesFrankrijk[a][3];
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswerFrankrijk(int a) {
        return mCorrectAnswersFrankrijk[a];
    }
```

Comment: 1. Create `Question` class. 2. Put questions into an `ArrayList<Question>`. 3. Call `Java.util.Collections.shuffle(...)` on that same ArrayList. 4. Done.

Comment: Or put the questions in a database table, then retrieve them using the `ORDER BY RANDOM` clause. And fill your ListView with the returned cursoradapter.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Should I create that Question class inside the question library or should it be a whole new activity? I don't really understand how to implement your solution in my code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of organizing your questions, choices, and answers into 3 separate arrays, you can create a new class, `Question`, which encapsulates all the information related to a question:

```
public class Question {
    private String mQuestionText;
    private List<String> mChoices;
    private String mAnswer;

    public Question(String questionText, @Size (4) String[] choices, String answer)
        mQuestionText = questionText;
        mChoices = Arrays.asList(choices);
        mAnswer = answer;
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return mQuestionText;
    }

    public List<String> getChoices() {
        return mChoices;
    }

    public String getAnswer() {
        return mAnswer;
    }
}
```

Now you can organize these `Question` objects into a `List` within your `QuestionLibrary`. By doing so, you'll be able to make use of the `java.util.Collections.shuffle()` utility method to randomly re-order your list. You may want to include a constructor in your `QuestionLibrary` class that does all this initial set up for you:

e.g.

```
public class QuestionLibrary {
    List<Question> mQuestionsList; // your List of Questions

    public QuestionLibrary() {
        mQuestionsList = new ArrayList<Question>();

        // add each question and corresponding choices / answers into the list
        mQuestionsList.add(new Question(
            "Wat is de hoofdstad van Frankrijk?",
            {"Lyon", "Parijs", "Nice", "Bordeaux"},
            "Parijs"
        ));

        ...

        mQuestionsList.add(new Question(
            "Hoeveel departemeneten zijn er in Frankrijk?",
            {"66", "76", "86", "96"},
            "96"
        ));

        // randomize the order of the list
        Collections.shuffle(mQuestionList);
    }
}
```

The order of your list will be randomized after instantiating a `QuestionLibrary` object. You can then create a getter method in your `QuestionLibrary` class to simply retrieve the next `Question` in the list.

```
public class QuestionLibrary {

    ...

    public Question getNextQuestion() {
        if (mQuestionList.isEmpty()) {
            return null; // no more Questions left
        } else {
           return mQuestionList.remove(0); // remove and return the next Question from the list
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can modify your `updateQuestion` method to get the next available `Question`, if any, and update your UI accordingly:

```
private void updateQuestion() {
    Question nextQuestion = mQuestionLibrary.getNextQuestion();
    if (nextQuestion == null) {
        // No more questions! Do something here
    } else {
        // Get the question text, answer and choices
        String questionText = nextQuestion.getQuestionText();
        String answer = nextQuestion.getAnswer();
        List<String> choices = nextQuestion.getChoices();
        Collections.shuffle(choices); // you can shuffle the order of the choices, too

        // update your UI using the above
        ...

    }
}
```